# MLA8 Refer to Multiple Subpages with One Citation

Tags: citations, academic-writing, mla

Is there a way to refer to different subpages of a website in text while only citing its main directory in the works cited?

For example, the hypothetical webpage, *www.example.com*, has the following hierarchy:

- www.example.com/

  - /sub1
  - /sub2
  - /sub3

Ordinarily, it would be cited in the *works cited* like this:

```
    Doe, John, et al. “Webpage Title.”
        http://www.example.com/main/sub1

    Doe, John, et al. “Webpage Title.”
        http://www.example.com/main/sub2

    Doe, John, et al. “Webpage Title.”
        http://www.example.com/main/sub3
```

However, would this be a legal *works cited* citation:

```
    Doe, John, et al. “Webpage Title.”
        http://www.example.com/main/
```

Following, would this be a legal *in text* citation for a subpage:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua (Doe /sub1).
```

Comment: Why would you put a space between "Doe" and "/sub1"? If you used a space, i think it should be between "sub" and "1"; i.e., (Doe/sub 1). "1" is too easily mistaken for the letter "l."

Comment: @MarkHubbard I assume that citing multiple webpages would follow similar conventions of author-page style in text citations. Since there are no official conventions, it was just an educated guess.

Comment: I suppose the #1 thing you'd want to ask yourself in that case is: "is it clear what's being referred to?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be a legal citation if done properly. Check out this excerpt from [this](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/08/) link about citing a whole website:

> It is a good idea to list your date of access because web postings are often updated, and information available on one date may no longer be available later. When using the URL, be sure to include the complete address for the site except for the https://.
>   Editor, author, or compiler name (if available). Name of Site. Version number, Name of institution/organization affiliated with the site (sponsor or publisher), date of resource creation (if available), URL, DOI or permalink. Date of access (if applicable).
>
> The Purdue OWL Family of Sites. The Writing Lab and OWL at Purdue and Purdue U, 2008, owl.english.purdue.edu/owl. Accessed 23 Apr. 2008.
>
> Felluga, Dino. Guide to Literary and Critical Theory. Purdue U, 28 Nov. 2003, www.cla.purdue.edu/english/theory/. Accessed 10 May 2006.

For the internal citations you need only to reference the website name/author depending on what you have. You probably want to check with your teacher considering some teacher have different preferences. Look [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/) for info on citations.